# Trying to understanding a geom_smooth error

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

Can someone please help me understand why the first line of code works, but not the second? I'm relatively new to R and would appreciate any help I can get!

```
ggplot(penguins, aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)

ggplot(penguins) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

for more context, I get the following error for the second line:
Error in `geom_smooth()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
! `stat_smooth()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The mapping for each layer (i.e. the stuff inside each  `aes` call) is by default inherited from the initial `ggplot()` call. Using `aes` inside one layer (e.g. inside the `geom_point` call) only affects that layer. So in your first version, both the geom_point and geom_smooth layers correctly inherit their x and y aesthetics from the plot object. In the second version, geom_smooth has no x or y aesthetics defined because there is no mapping to inherit - it can't inherit from the geom_point layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  when posting a question. You should include `require('ggplot2')` and `require('palmerpenguins')`

The `ggplot2` vignette explicitly says:

> mapping
>
> ```
> Default list of aesthetic mappings to use for plot. If not specified, must be supplied in each layer added to the plot.
> ```

In your second alternative, you supply the mapping argument for the `geom_point()` layer but not for the `geom_smooth()` layer.

Therefore the following block of code will work:

```
ggplot(penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)) + geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g), method=lm, se=FALSE)
```